# It is possible connect a QML Object existing signal in C++ QObject::connect()?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, signals-slots

The QML TreeView has an signal named: doubleClicked(QModelIndex)

ref: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qml-qtquick-controls-treeview.html#doubleClicked-signal

Its possible connect that existing signal in a C++ QObject::connect() ??

I tried this:

```
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
QObject *myTreeMenu = engine.rootObjects().at(0)->findChild<QObject*>("myTreeMenu");
connect(myTreeMenu , SIGNAL(doubleClicked(QModelIndex)), this, SLOT(slotModelClicked(QModelIndex)));
```

But i receive this return error:

```
QObject::connect: No such signal TreeView_QMLTYPE_63_QML_68::doubleClicked(QModelIndex) in '...'
QObject::connect:  (sender name:   'myTreeMenu ')
```

Comment: This part of the documentation might be helpful: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-interactqmlfromcpp.html#connecting-to-qml-signals

Comment: @Justin i saw that, but in this part they recreate the signal, i would to know if its possible connect with an already existing signal

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [documentation for Qt 5.11](http://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.11/qtquick-bestpractices.html#interacting-with-qml-from-c) explains why this is not the best way to work with C++ and QML. I would suggest you instead expose a slot or `Q_INVOKABLE` in your C++ object and call that in the `onDoubleClicked` handler:

```
Q_INVOKABLE void doStuff();
```

in QML:

```
onDoubleClicked: cppObject.doStuff()
```

The documentation has a "before and after" example demonstrating this; here's the bulk of it:

> With this approach, references to objects are "pulled" from QML. The
>   problem with this is that the C++ logic layer depends on the QML
>   presentation layer. If we were to refactor the QML in such a way that
>   the objectName changes, or some other change breaks the ability for
>   the C++ to find the QML object, our workflow becomes much more
>   complicated and tedious.
>
> Refactoring QML is a lot easier than refactoring C++, so in order to
>   make maintenance pain-free, we should strive to keep C++ types unaware
>   of QML as much as possible. This can be achieved by "pushing"
>   references to C++ types into QML:
>
> ```
> int main(int argc, char *argv[])
> {
>     QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
>
>     Backend backend;
>
>     QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
>     engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("backend", &backend);
>     engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
>     if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
>         return -1;
>
>     return app.exec();
> }
> ```
>
> The QML then calls the C++ slot directly:
>
> ```
> import QtQuick 2.11
> import QtQuick.Controls 2.4
>
> Page {
>     Button {
>         text: qsTr("Restore default settings")
>         onClicked: backend.restoreDefaults()
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> With this approach, the C++ remains unchanged in the event that the
>   QML needs to be refactored in the future.
>
> In the example above, we set a context property on the root context to
>   expose the C++ object to QML. This means that the property is
>   available to every component loaded by the engine. Context properties
>   are useful for objects that must be available as soon as the QML is
>   loaded and cannot be instantiated in QML.
>
> [Integrating QML and C++](http://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.11/qtqml-cppintegration-topic.html) demonstrates an alternative approach where QML
>   is made aware of a C++ type so that it can instantiate it itself.